# How to make org-mode not to highlight Sunday (in bold) as weekend?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a way to make org-mode and/or calendar **not** to highlight Sunday (in bold/red) as weekend in the Weekly Agenda/3 Months Calendar views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize `org-agenda-weekend-days`. Documentation says:

> Which days are weekend? Hide These days get the special face
>   ‘org-agenda-date-weekend’ in the agenda and timeline buffers.

Comment: Is there a similiar Emacs-wide variable, so it works also for the Calendar mode?

Comment: For calendar, you'd have to customize the calendar-weekend-header face. There is no emacs-wide variable.